# Node Reference translation

Tags: nodes

I'm turning one of my sites into a multi-lingual site, everything seems to work fine, only some fields where the Node Reference module was used don't seem to translated, even though the referenced node is translated to both languages.

Is there a fix for this? Or would I have to change something myself in order to get this to work?

Comment: Are you translating the site yourself?  Or are you using the translations included as part of Drupal?

Comment: I'm using the l18n module, the entire site is basically already translated, I'm just having trouble translating the node references. They are translated in the back-end, but are not showing up when switching to that language.